# Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "{" (8:16) - Problem with arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

i'm new to React and i'm creating a form following a internet tutorial, but just in the start i've run into this error: Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "{" (8:16)

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Form from './components/Form.js';

const handleSubmit = values => alert(JSON.stringify(values));
const initialValues = {}

function App() =>(
  <div>
    <Form handleSubmit={handleSubmit} initialValues={initialValues} />
  </div>
)

export default App;
```

Comment: App is **not** an arrow function, that's the problem.

Comment: `const App = () => (...)` or `function App() { return ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be an arrow function:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Form handleSubmit={handleSubmit} initialValues={initialValues} />
  </div>
);
```

or a normal function with a `return`:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form handleSubmit={handleSubmit} initialValues={initialValues} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

More about functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Answer (score 0):

Additional you can pass the brackets comes after App if function has one parameter.

```html
const App = parameterA => (
  <div>
    <Form handleSubmit={handleSubmit} initialValues={initialValues} />
  </div>
);
```